# transitionFromView not working

Tags: ios

In my previous project I used transitionFromView successfully, now I created new project today this time its ARC enabled, I copied the old code and pasted it but its not working. I put a breakpoint, executed it step by step but not working.

working code

```
quiz *quizObj = [[quiz alloc]init];
self.vc = quizObj;
[quizObj release];

[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.vc.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Not working code

```
EnterPhoneNumber *epnObj = [[EnterPhoneNumber alloc]init];

        [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:epnObj.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
```

project has no warnings or errors, but still this code is not working.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me

Comment: i don't know why its not working at my side. Can i send you the project, its very small.

Comment: i tried another thing that i tried to call this on button tap and it worked, I was calling it inside viewdidload, and my requirement is to call it inside viewdidload. I check internet connectivity available then switch to another view....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tries to put the method inside a performSelector

```
...
[self performSelector:@selector(actionView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
...

- (void)actionView {
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.vc.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
}
```

Comment: it worked now, but whats the reason that its not working directly inside   viewdidload.?

Comment: I think for the fact that should be included within the viewWillAppear for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more info on why it works when you delay it to another turn of the run loop:
http://andrewmarinov.com/working-with-uiviews-transition-animations/